# LARADOCK (laravel) container and MAILCOW docker container conflicting

Tags: nginx, debian, reverse-proxy, docker, port-forwarding

*I´m using Debian 9.*
**PROBLEM:** I can only reach my subdomain by appending a specific port
**Summary:** I´m running two docker containers ([laradock](https://www.laradock.io) and [mailcow](https://www.mailcow.email)). Both of them have their own instance of a web server (laradock: caddy, mailcow: nginx). Since I´m prioritizing my laradock container, it is the one blocking/using ports 80 and 443 (on localhost) for incoming http(s) traffic. My other container with nginx (mailcow) is listening to ports 8089 (http) and 8090 (https) on 0.0.0.0. I want to re-route all requests to webmail.mydomain.com, probably using caddy as a reverse-proxy in this case, to the ports utilized by mailcow. My attempts configuring a reverse-proxy with the not-so-well-known-caddy have failed with 502 gateway errors until now (and I can´t use nginx for my laradock container). Can anybody provide a solution to my problem? This doesn´t have to include port forwarding/reverse proxies.

Comment: In your config you have `https://abc.example.com` --> `http://abc.example.com:8090` but then you say `https://abc.example.com:8090 directly` is one of those a typo.

Comment: @Drifter104 sry typo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using nginx on my main system as a reverse proxy for both caddy and mailcow.